# About arrays and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

A brief question to do mainly with understanding how pointers work with arrays in this example:

```
char *lineptr[MAXLENGTH]
```

Now I understand this is the same as `char **lineptr` as an array in itself is a pointer.

My question is how it works in its different forms/ de-referenced states such as:

```
lineptr
*lineptr
**lineptr
*lineptr[]
```

In each of those states, whats happening, what does each state do/work as in code?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I understand this is the same as `char **lineptr` as an array in itself is a pointer.

No, an array is not the same as a pointer.  See the C FAQ: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html.

```
lineptr
```

This is the array itself.  In most situations, it **decays** into a pointer to its first element (i.e. `&lineptr[0]`).  So its type is either `int *[MAXLENGTH]` or `int **`.

```
*lineptr
```

This dereferences the pointer to the first element, so it's the value of the first element (i.e. it's the same as `lineptr[0]`).  Its type is `int *`.

```
**lineptr
```

This dereferences the first elements (i.e. it's the same as `*lineptr[0]`).  Its type is `int`.

```
*lineptr[]
```

I don't think this is valid syntax (in this context).

Comment: I am trying to create an Array of Arrays, i.e. an Array, whereby each element is an array of characters, a string. *lineptr[] is needed in this case? (I am trying to follow the K and R book (page 98))

Comment: @user1048116: Yes, each element of `lineptr` could be a pointer to a `char` array.

Answer (score 1):

`lineptr` is the /array/ itself.

`*lineptr` is the first element of the array, a char *

`**lineptr` is the char pointed to by the first element of the array

`*lineptr[N]` is the char pointed to by the Nth element of the array

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first things first.

Arrays are not pointers. They simply decompose to pointers when needed. Think of an array as a pointer that already has some data malloced/alloca'ed to it.

---

`lineptr` : This simply returns the array. Not much to say.

`*lineptr` : This is the same as accessing your array's first location. `*lineptr` = `lineptr[0]`. This just happens to return a `char *`

`**lineptr`: This is accessing the array's first location, an then dereferencing that location. `**lineptr` = `*(lineptr[0])`. Since your array holds `char*` this will return the `char` stored at the `char *` in slot 0 of the array.

`*lineptr[i]` : This dereferences the `char*` stored at i. So the `char` pointed to by `lineptr[i]` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be replaced with ("decay to") an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.

The expression `lineptr` has type "`MAXLENGTH`-element array of `char *`".  Under most circumstances, it will be replaced with an expression of type `char **`.  Here's a handy table showing all the possibilities:

```
Expression      Type                  Decays to  Evaluates to
----------      ----                  ---------  ------------
  lineptr       char *[MAXLENGTH]     char **    address of first element in array
 &lineptr       char *(*)[MAXLENGTH]  n/a        address of array
 *lineptr       char *                n/a        value of first element
  lineptr[i]    char *                n/a        value of i'th element 
 &lineptr[i]    char **               n/a        address of i'th element 
 *lineptr[i]    char                  n/a        value of character pointed to by i'th element
**lineptr       char                  n/a        value of character pointed to by zero'th element
```

Note that `lineptr` and `&lineptr` evaluate to the same *value* (the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element), but their types are different (`char **` vs. `char *(*)[MAXLENGTH]`).